# function for multiple validations

Tags: python, function

I need to create a python function, to accept id and list of values and compare it with the data to perform checks -
Data Table - 
[sample data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGESR.png)

```
def check(id,measures)
```

User will pass id and measures in the below format

validate passed length of "measures"
check whether measures are less than or equal to the corresponding values in the table.

```
check(5,[50,0])
```

like here [50,0] is <= [100,0] and hence

> > True

```
check(2,[50])
```

here [50] is not less than or equal to [5] and hence

> > False

```
check(5,[50])
```

here id:5 needs 2 measures to compare and hence below exception -

> > Missing measure for id:5, please pass 2 measures

```
check(3, [2,10,6,8,15,12])
```

here id:3 has required 6 measures but 10 (2nd value) is not less than 4
also 15 (5th value) is not less than 10
and hence

> > False

Comment: I do not understand what `[50,0] is <= [100,0]` means, especially when `[100,0]` is not mentioned in the question elsewhere.

Comment: [100,0] is row in the actual data set, refer the attached image "sample data table". [50,0] is compared with [100,0] one value at a time like 50 <=100 , 0<=0

Comment: You risk running into some severe unexpected problems downstream when the type of one of your columns is list(). Housing lists as individual items is generally bad practice in pandas. If you can't get around this issue perhaps you should consider not using a dataframe for this problem.

Comment: Now I need it as a primary solution on a larger scale will be planning to split each item into a column.

Comment: any suggestion if i store it in multiple columns, instead of a list in a single column